# how to remove numbers and symbols from output of LDA while using Gensim package?

Tags: python, lda, gensim

how to remove these numbers from output of LDA while using Gensim package?

2015-08-25 15:26:20,439 : INFO : topic #8 (0.100): 0.038*watch + 0.020*water + 0.014*strap + 0.011*analog + 0.011*resistance + 0.010*atm + 0.010*coloured + 0.010*timepiece + 0.010*5 + 0.009*classy

so that output will be  watch,water,strap...etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [show_topic](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html#gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel.show_topic) which returns a list of tuples (prob, word) and then print the words using for example :

```
topic_tuple = lda.show_topic(0, 10)

print ','.join([str(word_tuple[1]) for word_tuple in topic_tuple])
```

Based on [gensim source code](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/ldamodel.py#L741)